# Aggregate value when condition and partition by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table and I need to aggregate

```
Id     Month    Days    Hours  Audit
1      201803    20      30     Yes
1      201803    20      15     Yes
1      201802    19       4      No
2      201803    20       5     Yes
```

Expected output:

```
Id      Month    Days    Hours Audit  Total
 1      201803    20       2    Yes    100
 1      201803    20       3    Yes    100
 1      201802    10       4    No     
 2      201803    20       5    Yes    100
```

Summary:
Partition by ID & Month
Aggregate Days & Hours

My SQL: (my work)

```
SELECT (CASE
        WHEN AUDIT IN ('YES') 
        THEN HOURS * DAYS
        END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ,c.month) AS TOTAL
FROM TABLEA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sum` as the window function.

```
SELECT t.*,SUM(CASE WHEN AUDIT = 'YES' THEN HOURS * DAYS END) 
           OVER(PARTITION BY ID,month) AS TOTAL
FROM TABLEA t
```